# How to Share a Object between two threads (Thread Synchronization)?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I have two threads. One records the audio data into the variable. Another Thread sends that recorded variable to the server. What do I need to do in terms of concurrency, since I am new to multi-threading?

Below is the code snippet:

```
short[] sData = new short[1024];

recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
            while (isRecording) {
                recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
            }

        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
    recordingThread.start();
```

and another Thread which is accessing same sData and sending it to the server:

```
Thread sendThread= new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
                android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
    while (true) {
        try {

      ByteBuffer.wrap(bData).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
            .asShortBuffer().put(sData);            
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: you may mark your array as `final static`

Comment: Should use AsyncTask on android :)

Comment: @AndersMetnik by using AsyncTask taking more delay. Its works like 1request = 1response.

Comment: you should use "Atomic" or "syncronization"

Comment: @TechEnd My bad, didn't see it was continuous :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects to your question.

- Assuming that `sData` is a local variable, all you need to do to get the two Threads to share the array is to declare `sData` as `final`.  (And if `sData` is an instance or class variable you don't even need to do that ...)
- Getting the two threads to share the array *safely* is a bit harder.  The problem is that the two threads need to synchronize.  The send thread needs to know what part of the array that the record thread has written to.  Furthermore, synchronization is necessary to ensure that data written by the record thread is visible to the send thread.

In this example, proper synchronization will most likely entail a couple of extra variables to indicate the current positions of the two threads.  And since you have to deal with the cases where one thread needs to wait for the other to add or send data, you probably need to use `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()` to avoid busy waiting.

---

But what you are doing at the semantic level looks as if it needs to operate like a classical circular buffer of `short` values.  So I'd recommend looking for an existing implementation that you can reuse.  (For example, if you were willing to take the overhead of `Short` versus `short` then you could use an `ArrayBlockingQueue<Short>`.)

Comment: @Stephen... Yeah exactly you are right i have to use wait() and notify() methods to get rid of this problem

Answer (score 3):

To minimize reinventing the wheel, you can implement it as producer/consumer synchronization.For starters:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html

Just in case, some introductory stuff is here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to use a [latch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) if this is a one off operation or a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) if this needs to be repeated.